# Does `git submodule update` actually mean `git restore submodule to last commited state`?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have read some of the better question and answers regarding `git submodule update`. I am still a little confused about an aspect and want to clarify.

The term "`update`" in `git submodule update` triggered me to the assumption that, since a subumodule being another project/repo which might evolve, that an we are talking about importing those changes into the local copy of the submodule.

Can an answer to this question please clarify that if instead the action caused by calling `git submodule update` is not the action before, but instead would mean `git submodule restore_submodule_to_commit_state_of_which_was_commited_in_the_superproject`?

Comment: It seems like a little experimenting with a couple of local git repositories would quickly yield an answer to this question.

Comment: @larsks actually my question, was to clarify that what I indeed tested already (as you well suggested), yet there are lots of options related to `git submodule update` which all I could not test), my gut feeling is that the term `update` is not really concise here. If you are able to confirm or even give a clear citation/ doc/ref in an answer, that indeed the submodule update, is setting the submodule (back/forward) to the point of the commit, that would be an answer I would like to accept. I cannot answer myselft, as I do not know for sure, all I did is tests.